# Get string variable from .txt file - error C2784

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, boolean, c++-cli, ifstream

What I've done is I've written a program which, depending on a radio button selection, will either write "True" or "False" to a text file (preferences.txt) as a string. In a second program, I want it to read this file on the Load event and depending on what is present, either hide a bunch of controls or do nothing. The code is below:

```
String^ hostScreenChoice;

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         ifstream prefFile ("preferences.txt");     //FIX THIS

         getline(prefFile, hostScreenChoice);

         if (hostScreenChoice == "True")
         {
             //DO NOTHING, CONTINUE
         }

         else if (hostScreenChoice == "False")
         {
             //HIDE CONTROLS
         }
```

Now I'm relatively new to C++/CLI (In hindsight, I probably should have begun learning C# .NET), so as expected at a beginner level, I got a couple of errors.

```
error C2784: could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::ifstream'
```

was the offending error. I've scrolled through the internet but had no luck so far, although I think it may be due to the way I've declared the string but I'm not sure. Can you guys help me or is there a more efficient way of doing what I'm attempting? I'm using VS 2010 Express as my IDE.

Comment: It would be much easier if you used `.NET` types like `FileStream` or `StreamReader` etc.

Comment: @t3chb0t Mind changing this to an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: done - answer added ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are programming in `C++` it doesn't necessarily mean you are forced to use the native `C++` functions. `C++/CLI` offers you the whole package of `.NET` so I think it would be much easier to read the file by using the [FileStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) or the [StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).